# Multiple simultaneous Ajax requests are slow

Tags: javascript, ajax

If I call multiple API using Ajax at the same time, it is very slow, it seems javascript waits until getting all API's responses, not getting response asynchronously.

For example, 
/api/test1 response in 5 sec in usual,
and /api/test2 response in 5 sec in usual.

but if I call them at the same time, it takes 10 sec.

Example) it takes 10 sec

```
$.get("/api/test1", function() {
    self.responseHandler1();
});
 $.get("/api/test2", function() {
    self.responseHandler2();
});
```

So to make it load faster I do for now,

```
$.get("/api/test1", function() { // 5 sec
    self.responseHandler1(); 
    $.get("/api/test2", function() { // 5 sec
        self.responseHandler2();
    });
});
```

But I think there is some nicer way, please advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
$.get("/api/test1", function() {
    self.responseHandler1();
    $.get("/api/test2", function() {
        self.responseHandler2();
    });
});
```

doesn't get test2 until test1 has been retrieved

This code

```
$.get("/api/test1", function() {
    self.responseHandler1();
});
$.get("/api/test2", function() {
    self.responseHandler2();
});
```

retrieves the two requests *in parallel*

and this code

```
$.when($.get("/api/test1"), $.get("/api/test2")).then(function(resp1, resp2) {
    self.responseHandler1();
    self.responseHandler2();
});
```

makes the requests in parallel, but runs both response handlers only once both requests have completed

as a test (regarding the changed code in the question and the comment below)

```
var x = Date.now();
$.get("/api/test1", function() {
    self.responseHandler1();
});
console.log(x - Date.now());
$.get("/api/test2", function() {
    self.responseHandler2();
});
console.log(x - Date.now());
```

The two values logged to console should be small numbers (easily less than 100) - if they are not, then your `$.get` isn't asynchronous - my jQuery knowledge is hazy, but I think there's a way to make the default request synchronous, which may be what some part of your code has done - otherwise, the issue is with the server, perhaps it can't handle simultaneous requests, or perhaps whatever the api code is doing on the server is blocking - either way, if those to logged numbers are small, the problem exists with the server

Comment: If I request multiple in parallel, it takes more time. could it be server side issue? PHP couldn't handle multiple requests at the same time?

Comment: what? you changed the code in the question - are you saying either way it takes 10 seconds? perhaps the server can only deal with one request at a time, therefore series/parallel wont make a lick of difference